# Dispose vs. Iterator blocks

Tags: c#, ienumerable, dispose, yield-return, ienumerator

These two questions almost answer my own question, but not quite.  Consider this a follow-up question to these.

- [Do I need to consider disposing of any IEnumerable<T> I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459447/do-i-need-to-consider-disposing-of-any-ienumerablet-i-use)
- [Understanding Iterator Blocks and Dispose Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872633/understanding-iterator-blocks-and-dispose-method)

I understand that a `foreach` loop will `Dispose` of an enumerator when it's done with it.

My question is this:

If the enumerator in question is actually a c# iterator block (i.e. `GetEnumerator()/yield`) of an `IEnumerable<T>` class which itself implements `IDisposable`, can I be sure that the object itself will be disposed?  Or do I need to resort to calling `GetEnumerator()/MoveNext()/Current` explicitly inside a `using` block?

**EDIT:**  [This snippet](http://ideone.com/XRWGq9) demonstrates @JonSkeet's answer.

**EDIT #2:**  [This snippet](http://ideone.com/PrjAEc), based on @JonSkeet's comments, demonstrates ideal usage.  The iterator block is responsible for the lifetime of needed resources, not the enumerable object itself.  This way, the enumerable can be enumerated multiple times if need be -- each enumerable has its own resource to work with.

Comment: Can you post a SSCCE? (Doing so and running it might answer the question anyway.) I don't quite follow the question: no actions with an enumerator will cause the collection object it belongs to to be disposed.

Comment: The caller cannot tell how the iterator method was implemented. A different .NET language might not even know that concept.

Comment: Are you asking if doing `foreach` over an `IEnumerator<T> where T : IEnumerable<U>, IDisposable` will dispose the objects of type `U`? Of course not, why would it do that? If I enumerate a collection of open sockets should the sockets be automatically closed?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean - are you trying to dispose of each object returned via the iterator?

Comment: @JonSkeet No, I'm trying to ensure that the Enumerable is disposed.  Imagine that its constructor gets a file handle and the iterator block yields each line in the file.

Comment: @CSJ You already know that.  I know that you know that because you say so right in your question, "I understand that a foreach loop will Dispose of an enumerator when it's done with it."

Comment: @Servy No, I know that the anonymous thing doing the enumerating will be disposed; it's not clear whether the object that served up the enumerator (i.e. the enumerable) will also be disposed.  That's my question.

Comment: @CSJ It doesn't implement `IDisposable`, and *has* no `Dispose` method, so it *cannot* be disposed.  `IEnumerator<T>` extends `IDisposable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Servy In my original question I stipulate that my IEnumerable also implements IDisposable explicitly.

Comment: @CSJ It's an iterator block.  You couldn't make it do that even if you tried.  It's a compiler generated class.  If you had a custom object, i.e. **not** an iterator block, then it could implement `IDisposable`, and `foreach` would not dispose of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to dispose of the `IEnumerable<T>`, you need to do that yourself with a `using` statement (or manual try/finally). A `foreach` loop does *not* dispose of the `IEnumerable<T>` automatically - only the iterator it returns.

So, you'd need:

```
using (var enumerable = new MyEnumerable())
{
    foreach (var element in enumerable)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It makes no difference whatsoever whether `MyEnumerable` implements `IEnumerable<T>` using an iterator block or some other code.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  An alternative is to do any cleanup inside the iterator block itself before it quits (e.g. by calling `this.Dispose()` directly in front of `yield break`, for example)

Comment: @CSJ: You would have to do something like `using (this) { ... }` - don't forget that `foreach` may not iterate over the whole of the iterator's contents. I would strongly suggest that you *don't* do this, however. It would be very non-idiomatic, to say the least, for iterating over a sequence to dispose of the sequence itself. It sounds like a reasonably odd design to start with...

Comment: I see.  It seems I'm more interested in building an enumerator than an enumerable.

Comment: @CSJ Again, it's not *possible* to write an iterator block that generates an `IEnumerable` that is disposable, so having it dispose of itself inside of the iterator block is a moot point.  Not that that's the only roadblock.  It would need to be a non-iterator block `IEnumerable`.  And on top of that, there would need to be some way for the `IEnumerator` to know what `IEnumerable` created it.  It's a potentially solvable problem, but still bad practice, and entirely unnecessary.  If you're in such a situation simply don't create the disposable resource in the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Servy: Actually, in practice the `IEnumerable<T>` returned from an iterator block *does* implement `IDisposable`. It's a bit of a hack for the sake of efficiency. But I agree that one shouldn't *expect* it to :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, in any case, you couldn't run any of your code when it's disposed, so it may as well not be `IDisposable` from his perspective.

Comment: I'm trying to create an experience similar to `foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines()) { ... } without forcing the caller to dispose anything, but not leaving any handles lying around.  Looks like the object returned should be an enumerator, not an enumerable.

Comment: @CSJ: If you *only* open the handles within the iterator block, and do that within a `using` statement, it'll be fine. When the iterator is disposed, that will invoke any appropriate `finally` blocks (including implicit ones from `using` statements) in the iterator block.

Comment: @CSJ The key there is that the `IEnumerable` doesn't open up any resources.  It is the `IEnumerator` that actually opens up the file.  `File.ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable` (not an `IEnumerator`) that, each time it is asked to create a new `IEnumerator`, opens a new file.  Follow that pattern.  You don't need to (and likely don't want to) have your method itself return an `IEnumerator`.

Comment: @Servy: I completely agree with the sentiment - but `File.ReadLines` is a bad example because it's implemented so badly. If it had been implemented appropriately, everything you say would be true :)

Comment: @JonSkeet We're getting a bit offtopic here, but how does it differ from that?

Comment: @Servy: By the looks of it, it actually opens the file *immediately* - and maintains a single reader however many times you call `GetEnumerator` on it. Try `var lines = File.ReadLines("test.txt"); foreach (var x in lines) { foreach (var y in lines) { Console.WriteLine(x + " " + y); } }` and see what happens with a `test.txt` of `n` lines. It *should* show `n^2` lines... but it doesn't :(

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, yeah.  Apparently it handles subsequent reads just fine: `lines.Count();lines.Count();` is fine.  The issue is that calling `GetEnumerator` *while another iterator is currently iterating the file* returns the same handle, rather than a separate one.  Calling `GetEnumerator` after the previous call finishes isn't a problem.  A slightly simpler way of demonstrating this than your code is `foreach (var line in lines) Console.WriteLine(lines.Count());`, which throws an object disposed exception, instead of just printing the number of lines N times.

Comment: @Servy: Right. And the fact that `var lines = File.ReadLines("test.txt");` opens the file *at all* is a problem, too. Bah.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't *think* that does though.  At the very least, I can't prove that it does.  I *believe* that it doesn't open the file until you first start iterating it.  It's just that it stores the file in some state shared between all `IEnumerator` instances.  Most likely this is because it returns an object that implements both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`, and the `Enumerable` returns itself.  So (if I'm right) it's not *so* bad (it's still not ideal though).

Comment: @Servy: I'll see if I can prove it to you... watch this space :)

Comment: @JonSkeet nevermind, you're right.  It does open the file.  Simple example: `var handle = File.OpenWrite("output.txt"); var lines = File.ReadLines("output.txt");`  (that throws an exception, it ideally shouldn't until `lines` creates an iterator.

Comment: @Servy: Right. I was going to try it the other way round: call ReadLines then Delete :)

Comment: @Servy, JonSkeet: Very interesting discussion, clearly pointing out the respective responsibilities of the enumerator vs. the enumerable.  So a reference example to _avoid_.

Comment: BTW, calling `Dispose` on an iterator before `GetEnumerator` has called has no effect; calling it after that time will dispose the very first enumerator created if it hasn't been disposed yet.

Comment: @supercat: By "an iterator" do you mean "the return returned from a method implemented with an iterator block"? If so, then I agree.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That is indeed what I meant.  The behavior is mostly harmless, but it illustrates one of the difficulties with assuming that object *instances* which happen to implement `IDisposable` need cleanup.

Answer (score 6):

`foreach` calls `Dispose` on the iterator regardless of the implementation of that iterator.  It doesn't matter if it was created with an iterator block or not, it's `Dispose` method is called either way.

That's the whole point of interfaces, such as `IDisposable`.  You don't need to *care* what the underlying implementation is.  It *always* disposes of *everything*.  What they choose to do with that call is up to them.

As for the `IEnumerable<T>` (not the `IEnumerator<T>`) generated by the iterator block, it *will never implement `IDisposable`*, and thus *cannot* be disposed.  If you have a custom object (rather than an iterator block) that implements `IEnumerable<T>` and `IDisposable`, then it will not be disposed of when used in a `foreach`.  Only the `IEnumerator<T>` created through `GetEnumerator` will be.

Comment: Actually iterators generated with a iterator block do implement dispose, however you need a try\finally to see it. [Here is a  example SSCCE of it](http://ideone.com/Z9sf2d)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's the `IEnumerator`, not the `IEnumerable`.  Big difference.  The `IEnumerable` does *not* have a dispose method.

Comment: Ahh, missed that. sorry.